# Facebook Graph API Explorer won't delete a request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to delete a request via Graph API Explorer. Request is generated by my mobile application. Of course, I use an access token from this application. And I've got the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#2) Failed to delete any app request",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2
  }
}
```

The request exists, I can GET it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I tried to delete a request that didn't belong to me.